# wsdl 404 problem

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I'm having problems with a web service.
I published the site on IIS 6. With my browser the interface works fine.
When I try to create a proxy with wsdl.exe, It gives me 404 not found error.

Is there any trigger in IIS that I should turn or what?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're facing an network related issue. I've seen such problems when a windows box has several IPs, e.g. when standing in an DMZ. If your machine has several IDs try using all of them, one after the other in your wsdl description. maybe this solves your problem.

if not i'd ask you to provide more details.

Comment: My computer has only 1 ip. It works the same way with my colleague.
What information do you need?

Comment: i c, Can you establish an connection to the service with WS testing tools? http://www.soapui.org/ is a good one IMHO. trying to narrow things down...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it's working.
The problem was that my internet connection was using a proxy, turned that off and now it's working.